# TypeError at /predict/ 'method' object is not subscriptable in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am doing prediction on a machine learning model using PyTorch and in Django rest framework. while loading I am getting `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable` error. How to rectify this error.
[image]
My `views.py` file

```py
response = {}
@api_view(['GET'])
def result(request):
    solute = request.POST.get['solute']
    solvent = request.POST.get['solvent']
    results = predictions(solute, solvent)
    response["predictions"] = results[0].item()
    response["interaction_map"] = (results[1].detach().numpy()).tolist()
    return Response({'result': response}, status=200)
```

`apps.py`

```py
class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'
    MODEL_FILE = os.path.join(settings.MODELS)
    model = joblib.load(MODEL_FILE)
```

`urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('predict/',result, name='result'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using square brackets not braces when you call get. Get is a method and you try accessing elements via an index. That explains the error.

Answer (score 1):

you should modify your code like below

```
solute = request.POST.get('solute')
solvent = request.POST.get('solvent')
```